# Maya Calendar from Elementary OS on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, compiling, calendar, elementary

The [Maya Calendar](https://launchpad.net/maya) from Elementary OS seems really nice:

[image]

Has anyone been able to run it on Ubuntu ? Is it available on some repository ? After installing the dependencies, I only get a ton of error messages when I try to build it from source. [This question](https://answers.launchpad.net/maya/+question/211650) on the official page has no positive answer yet.

Comment: No. AFAIK now Maya requires gtk-3.12, Contractor & Granite. You have to compile it/them from source in Gnome-3.12. I don't think it can be compiled against Gtk-3.10.

Comment: Yorba is working on a calendar app for GNOME named California. It is quite good (although still alpha). You can [download the app](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/daily-builds/+packages) and try it out.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to install Mayan Calendar on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maya-calendar
```

<sub>[Source](http://2buntu.com/articles/1429/the-mayan-calendar-is-back/)</sub>

Comment: Well, don't try this if you are a numix fans for it conflicts with some settings in numix.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want untested features use the 'stable' repo instead of 'daily'

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maya-calendar
```

Comment: This is a copy od the former answer.  Please refrain from doing that as it only add noise to the site.