# How do I install Maya Calendar (from Elementary OS) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, calendar

Please publish a simple guide on how to install Maya calendar on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried this question: [Maya Calendar from Elementary OS on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468899/maya-calendar-from-elementary-os-on-ubuntu), but I'm having a lot of problems with unmet dependencies. Thanks.

```
$ sudo apt-get install maya-calendar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 maya-calendar : Depends: libmaya-calendar0 (= 0.3.1.1+r816+pkg70~daily~ubuntu0.3.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgranite3 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.11.7) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
                 Recommends: maya-calendar-plugin-caldav but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: maya-calendar-plugin-google but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you mean by  *a lot of problems with unmet dependencies*? Just [edit] your question and show us the full output of `sudo apt-get install maya-calendar` that shows those error messages. Note that you should use code formatting (**`{}`**-button). Thank you and welcome on AskUbuntu.

Comment: "Note that you should use code formatting ({}-button)" - I don't know what this means.

Comment: When you [edit] your question, you see a button that looks like **`{}`**. It formats the passage you have selected properly as code. Use this e.g. for terminal outputs. For more information about formatting, see http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

`maya-calendar` is basically the `california` calendar from Yorba foundation.
I used the instructions in this link and it worked flawlessly: [Install California calendar](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/california-calendar-app-hits-yorba-daily-ppa)

In short use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/daily-builds
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install california
```

Comment: True! installs instantly and runs fine.

Comment: ...But is not really functional :(

Comment: Right after posting this answer, I installed `maya-calendar` too. It installed all the dependencies automatically, which is the real issue in this question. I believe if @richard-gordon installed the dependencies separately before installing `maya-calendar`, it will start working properly.