# Calendar app (Maya) from Elementary OS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: calendar, elementary

I would like to try the calendar app from Elementary OS in vanilla Ubuntu. I followed the instructions in [Maya Calendar from Elementary OS on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468899/maya-calendar-from-elementary-os-on-ubuntu), but they don't seem to work anymore; I guess the repo is outdated.

Is there a more recent source? Is that app still working in 2020, or has it been abandoned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [repology.org](https://repology.org/project/maya-calendar/versions) and then [OpenSuSe Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Leap:15.1:Update/maya-calendar) this package had latest version public of 0.4.1.

The upstream repository is at GitHub - https://github.com/elementary/calendar .

In the Ubuntu is it available from  [“elementary OS team” daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily?field.series_filter=focal).
So we need to get and install one dependency first:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhandy-1/libhandy-1-0_1.0.0-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libhandy-1-0_1.0.0-2_amd64.deb
```

and then use PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maya-calendar
```

Then run it from menu or from terminal by `io.elementary.calendar`.

Note: visually this application looks very similar to the default GNOME Calendar application, I'm not sure about functionality differences.

Comment: Thanks! This works, minus some theme trouble (the default font is white and only looks well on dark themes). Functionally, it seems quite different from gnome-calendar; if I understand correctly the codebase is from California, another abandoned calendar application for Gnome.

Comment: ⚠️ I would suggest to install from the "stable" channel rather than the "daily": `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable`.